# Can long int be returned by a function in c?

Tags: c, function, return

Suppose we want to return a **long integer** by a function.
How to do it?
Is it valid?

```
long int function()
{
  long int b;
  b=1000000000;
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is valid.

As long as you're retuning a proper `long int` value (which we can see, you're doing<sup>#</sup>) and catching that into another `long int` (you need to take care), it should be fine.

---

#) As per the `C11` standard, `LONG_MAX` is `+2147483647` and `1000000000` is less than that. Chapter §5.2.4.2.1, for reference.

Comment: Plus one for standard quotation.

Comment: @Bathsheba Appreciate that!! Gracious. :-)

Comment: I don't quite see what the value limits of a long have to do with the question.

Comment: I conject that Natasha, like me, wanted to examine the validity of the assignment `b=1000000000`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I read the question as "is it valid to return a long integer from a function", rather than "does the code in this example have well-defined behavior". Anyway, no biggie.

Answer (score 6):

### Can long int be returned by a function in c?

[image: Can long int be returned by a function in c?]

Comment: Apologies to the three detractors who clearly think I'm lowering the tone. But I and two others thought it was funny. So I'm saying the jury is still out on this one.

Comment: This answer continues to divide opinion but at least those in favour now out number those against.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard stipulates a minimum size of 32 bits for a `long int`, stored in such a way as to guarantee that values in the range [−2147483647, +2147483647] can be represented. (Note that a 2s compliment representation gives you −2147483648). So the assignment of 1,000,000,000 to a `long int` is always defined.

Returning a value copy of a `long int` is well-defined too.

Note that if you hadn't *initialised* `b` (i.e. if you had omitted the statement `b=1000000000;`), then the behaviour of your program would have been undefined.

Comment: I don't quite see what the value limits of a long have to do with the question.

Comment: How could you? I upvoted your answer :-) Seriously, it would have been very relevant had the OP, say had wanted to assign 10,000,000,000 to the `long int`. That's not always well-defined.

Comment: The type of the integer literal itself is the smallest possible that can fit the number, for the given system. But it is never smaller than `int`. This is well-defined in 6.4.4.1. In case of 10 billion, the compiler would likely pick type `long long int`.  If you then show that into a long, the following applies (6.3.1.3) `"Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."`. So something implementation-defined is guaranteed to happen.

Answer (score 2):

A function can return pretty much any type:

> 6.9.1
>
> The return type of a function shall be void or a complete object type other than array type.

And that's it.